# rbenv-capistrano install ruby version 1.9.3p392 instead of 1.9.3p448

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
myproject@ubuntu:~/Desktop/myproject$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
```

However when I run `cap deploy:setup` install in my production server ruby version `1.9.3p392`

My .ruby-version file:

```
1.9.3-p448
```

my capistrano-rbenv version is (1.0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think capistrano-rbenv installs a new ruby version itself, instead it uses the selected ruby version or in your case a similar version if the required version doesn't exist.

Also, you may still have configured another version in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3-p392' # somewhere perhaps
```

Comment: Thank you is correct. My rbenv-capistrano is old version. Thank you